# Как сделать чтобы он прочитывал txt документ и выводил строку с нужными аргументами?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно чтобы он выводил строку с определенными аргументами, то есть, я пишу !giftkey vip 30d, он прочитывает документ keys.txt в котором лежат ключи то есть:

```
sa76gs9d78g57ds9gds60sgd06gds | vip | 90d
afsashkfasdf707gh94sgf7h4hg8s | vip | 30d
sdgoia6sd987as59f6asgfasyr9fa | premium | LF
fglg98hdhgfh677dg8h95f9h657hd | vip | LF
sdfuigsdugifgsu123ib123g12kl3 | premium | 90d
```

Код который у меня есть:

```
@bot.command(name="giftkey", brief="Выдача ключа", usage="giftkey")
async def giftkey(ctx, arg1, arg2):

    with open("key.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:

        lines = file.readlines()

        lines_to_choice = ["vip"]
        lines_to_choise = ["premium"]

        lines_to_choice1 = ["30d"]
        lines_to_choise2 = ["90d"]

        for line in lines:
            if arg1 and arg2 in line:
                lines_to_choice.append(line)
                lines_to_choice1.append(line)
            elif arg1 and arg2 in line:
                lines_tochoise.append(line)
                lines_to_choise2.append(line)

        random_line = random.choice(lines_to_choice).strip()

    await ctx.send(random_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не используй текстовый файл, сделай хотя бы json

```
{
  "vip": {
    "30d": "afsashkfasdf707gh94sgf7h4hg8s",
    "90d": "sa76gs9d78g57ds9gds60sgd06gds",
    "LF": "fglg98hdhgfh677dg8h95f9h657hd"
  },
  "premium": {
    "90d": "sdfuigsdugifgsu123ib123g12kl3",
    "LF": "sdgoia6sd987as59f6asgfasyr9fa"
  }
}
```

Либо сделай словарь в питоне. И делай нормальные названия для переменных, а то весь код одно и тоже имя. C json или словарем проще парсить и тогда все получится

Comment: Надо именно txt, я предлагал json